# Compare URIs for a search bot?

Tags: http, url, http-status-codes, canonicalization

For a search bot, I am working on a design to:
* compare URIs and
* determine which URIs are really the same page

Dealing with redirects and aliases:
Case 1: Redirects
Case 2: Aliases e.g. www
Case 3: URL parameters e.g. sukshma.net/node#parameter

I have two approaches I could follow, one approach is to explicitly check for redirects to catch case #1. Another approach is to "hard code" aliases such as www, works in Case #2. The second approach (hard-code) aliases is brittle. The URL specification for HTTP does not mention the use of www as an alias (RFC 2616)

I also intend to use the Canonical Meta-tag (HTTP/HTML), but if I understand it correctly - I cannot rely on the tag to be there in all cases.

Do share your own experience. Do you know of a reference white paper implementation for detecting duplicates in search bots?

Comment: Man, this really smacks of being a job interview question.

Comment: Really, why would you think that? Is it the way I wrote the question out?

Answer (score 0):

Building your own web crawler is a [lot of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762235/how-do-web-spiders-differ-from-wgets-spider/852590#852590).  Consider checking out some of the open source spiders already available, like [JSpider](http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/), [OpenWebSpider](http://www.openwebspider.org/) or [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers).

Comment: I get where you are going, however - I need the technology and know-how for duplicated detection (and not just for crawls). Would you know if these projects have resolved that successfully?

Comment: Despite my own advice, I've built my own crawler and stored a checksum for every crawled page.  If a page was a potential duplicate of another, based on its URL or other criteria, then I compared the checksums to check.

Answer (score 0):

The **first case** would be solved by simply **checking the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code)**.

For the **2nd and 3rd cases** Wikipedia explains it very well: **[URL Normalization / Canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_normalization)**.