# How do I crawl all the pages on my internal website?

Tags: web-crawler

I want to hit every page on my internal website to see if any throw an error just from looking at them. The website does its own error logging, so I just need something to follow links.

I am running Windows XP and IIS.

Comment: Make it public and wait for Google? :P

Comment: You can use www.crawlmysite.in . Works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the IIS SEO toolkit.  Inspects your site for SEO related issues which includes broken links.

[IIS SEO Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit)

Answer (score 2):

```
wget --spider <URL>
```

edit- just noticed you said windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: you might want to check out this though:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762235/how-do-web-spiders-differ-from-wgets-spider